# GWT 2.0 with Selenium

Tags: unit-testing, testing, gwt, selenium-ide

I am trying to use Selenium IDE to record action and then make them run but it is not working. Is it possible to use Selenium IDE with GWT??
Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate on "not working"?

Comment: I am using gwt 2.1 for e.g when I press record on selenium ide and perform some clicks on cell browser, it does not record the events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's feasible. We are using extGWT with Selenium to test some parts of our client side.

We used this article to start:
http://www.sencha.com/blog/2008/11/03/testing-ext-js-ext-gwt-applications-with-selenium/

The important point on the GWT side is to assign unique IDs to widgets so that they are easy to reference from the Selenium script. If it's not feasible, use XPath.

Comment: Please have a look at this topic then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084233/selenium-testing-of-gwt-2-0